# Python: How to make multiple HTTP POST queries in one moment?

Tags: python, http, concurrency

How to make multiple HTTP POST queries in one moment using Python?

Using an external library with an example can be a good solution.

Comment: Define 'one moment', I don't think that term exists in modern computing... :X

Comment: Given your comment to Sleepingrock's question I think you need to make the question clearer

Answer (score 1):

External lib? Maybe an internal one would do the trick...

http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#examples

specifically:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
```

If you wanted to process multiple HTTP POST queries (asynchronous) you could cycle through them in a loop, opening subprocesses using `subprocess.Popen`. Although a better solution would probably be `asyncore`. [This site](http://effbot.org/librarybook/asyncore.htm) has an [example](http://effbot.org/librarybook/SimpleAsyncHTTP.py) of using asyncore for http requests (like POST).

Comment: No. It's synchronous request. While it process, app need to wait for continue next request

Comment: So you want asynchronous POST requests in Python?

Comment: Yes, asynchronous POST requests

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) (or maybe [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html), but here the [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) is not a problem) to enable concurrent execution.

Comment: Asyncore is primarily threading for sockets. It would be easier to implement in this case.